# RPC getnewaddress error on v 0.20.0

Tags: bitcoin-cli

I would like to new address generate with this command

`bitcoin-cli -testnet getnewaddress "adr1" "p2sh-segwit"`  but I get this msg:

```
error message:
Wallet file not specified (must request wallet RPC through /wallet/<filename> uri-path).
Try adding "-rpcwallet=<filename>" option to bitcoin-cli command line.
```

then I added the -rpcwallet command like that:
`bitcoin-cli -testnet -rpcwallet=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/ getnewaddress "adr1" "p2sh-segwit"`  but I got an error again like this:

`````
error message:
Requested wallet does not exist or is not loaded````

what should I do?

thank you
`````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-rpcwallet` takes the name of the wallet, not the path to the datadir (as you appear to have done) or the path to the wallet file.

To get a list of the names of the wallets currently loaded, you can use the `listwallets` command.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and had a hard time trying to figure out where to pass in the `-rpcwallet=<wallet_name>` flag. For example, I was doing a `bitcoin-cli listunspent -rpcwallet=<wallet_name>` and was getting the same error, until I changed things around and passed in the flag before the `listunspent` rpc command.

So always use the `-rpcwallet` flag before the rpc command you're working with.

For example:

`bitcoin-cli -rpcwallet=<wallet_name> listunspent` will work, but `bitcoin-cli listunspent -rpcwallet=<wallet_name>` will return with the same error.